# Generated valid label value (Kubernetes)

Tags: go, kubernetes

Label values in Kubernetes need to be valid.

See [IsValidLabelValue()](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/bfd2aff97e594f6aad77acbe2cbbe190acc93cbc/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L167)

For example the input I receive from a rest-API of a provider, which I want to write to a label: `Dedicated Server 1U`.

Is there a way to generate a valid label via Go from an arbitrary string?

Comment: can you give an example string please?

Comment: @akathimi for example: `Dedicated Server 1U`.

Comment: what is the expected label to be generated ?, and do you want the label to be generated using golang or bash ?

Comment: It should be done via Go, and I the exact result does not matter, as long as a human get decode it to "Dedicated Server 1U" with his eyes (so base64 is not an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have a function to do this, for example:

```
func generateLabel(input string) string {
    input = strings.Replace(input, " ", "-", -1)
    return "api-label=" + input
}
```

- the function replaces the spaces in the received string to "-"
- you can change the key to any string you like.
- you can also add a regex check to make sure that the generated value complies with the label constraints. (this depends if any special characters are being received from the API)

To accept the string even when there are unwanted characters, check the below:

```
package main

import (
        "regexp"
        "strings"
        "fmt"
)

func generateLabel(input string) string {
    input = strings.Replace(input, " ", "-", -1)
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]")
    input = re.ReplaceAllString(input, "")

    re = regexp.MustCompile("^[^a-zA-Z0-9]([-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$")
    input = re.ReplaceAllString(input, "")

    return "api-label=" + input
}

func main() {
    label := generateLabel("Dedicated Server 1U")
    fmt.Println(label) // Output: "api-label=Dedicated-Server-1U"

    label1 := generateLabel("Dedicated&test")
    fmt.Println(label1) // Output: "api-label=Dedicatedtest"

    label2 := generateLabel("Dedicated,test##&(*!great")
    fmt.Println(label2) // Output: "api-label=Dedicatedtestgreat"
}
```

Comment: Since I am not the creator of this string, the string could contain many more invalid characters like &, /, (, ...